# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props') for clicking on button in React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create two buttons that navigate to two other pages within my react app. I click on either button and I receive the following error when I click on the button marked home.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
onPress

   9 | <Button
  10 |     title="Go to Home"
  11 |     onPress={
> 12 |         () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
  13 | ^   }
  14 | />&nbsp;
  15 |
```

I receive the following error when I click on the button marked profile.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
onPress
  16 | <Button
  17 |     title="Go to Profile"
  18 |     onPress={
> 19 |         () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
  20 | 
  21 | ^   }
  22 | />
```

I receive the same error when I click on either button.
Below is the code for the three files I am working with.

Apps.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Home from './Screens/Home'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>&nbsp;
            <Button
                title="Go to Home"
                onPress={
                    () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
                }
            />&nbsp;

            <Button
                title="Go to Profile"
                onPress={
                    () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')
                }
            />
        </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

//import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigator';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const userName = this.props.navigation.getParam('')

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Hello from Profile Page</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Profile.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigator';

export default class Profile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Hello from Profile Page</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Comment: As you're using a function component for App, this keyword isn't applicable there.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apps.js is a functional component and the keyword `this` wouldn't work, plus nothing is passed in through `export default function App()`, what you might want to do is to replace `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')` with `props.navigation.navigate('Home')` and receives a props parameter by doing `export default function App(props)`